# How to make cmd the default terminal that gets opened in VSCode on opening VS Code.?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

When I open my VSCode the default terminal that gets opened is PowerShell. I wants the default one that gets opened to be CMD. How can I change it?

I have configured the `Terminal: Select Default Profile` to be CMD and its also made sure as seen in the below pic.

[image]

I restarted the VSCode several times, still on opening VS Code the terminal that gets opened is PowerShell. Should I make any changes to `settings.json`?

Comment: based on @mklement0 info, this is known problem and it will be fixed in the next version 1.60.1